# Script to open two applications on start up and snap them with one being 80% screen and the other being 20% in Windows 8.1 Desktop

Tags: powershell, wasp

I am not a programmer rather a designer but have been trying to write a .bat file for weeks to have two applications, which I specify, open automatically and snap to a scale of 80% left hand side and 20% for the second app on the right hand side.  I have looked into multiple options without having any luck. Currently, I can create a script to open two files and automate key strokes to have them snap 50-50%, however I really need the 80-20% screen real estate.  Any chance anyone would be able to help me out?

I am currently trying to use PowerShell with WASP (http://wasp.codeplex.com/) but scripting in this is beyond my knowledge.  Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you have been able to do and we can work with that?

Answer (score 1):

You should try [UI Automation PowerShell Extensions.](http://uiautomation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation%20for%20Metro%20UI%20testing&referringTitle=Documentation)

It supports testing for Metro Apps. The initial setup is a bit tedious (as described in the link provided) but it is well worth it. You have a UI action recording tool **UIAutomationSpy** which records all of your actions and generates corresponding PowerShell scripts.  You can then run these scripts using the **UIARunner** tool.

With respect to the current problem, you could simulate the steps for snapping the apps using the recorder. You could then create a task which runs a batch file (executing the concerned script) on startup.